# Can not make shared curl library

Tags: curl, makefile, arm, embedded, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling curl library for arm board.
So I configured Makefile using configure script file in curl library directory like this.

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --with-ssl=/tmp/openssl --prefix=/tmp/curl --host=arm
```

But the result is always static library. How do I fix it?

Configure result

```
  Host setup:       arm-unknown-none
  Install prefix:   /tmp/curl
  Compiler:         arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
   CFLAGS:          -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread
   CPPFLAGS:        -isystem /tmp/openssl/include -DOPENSSL_SUPPRESS_DEPRECATED
   LDFLAGS:         -L/tmp/openssl/lib
   LIBS:            -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto

  curl version:     7.73.0
  SSL:              enabled (OpenSSL v3+)
  SSH:              no      (--with-{libssh,libssh2})
  zlib:             no      (--with-zlib)
  brotli:           no      (--with-brotli)
  zstd:             no      (--with-zstd)
  GSS-API:          no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP:          enabled
  resolver:         POSIX threaded
  IPv6:             enabled
  Unix sockets:     enabled
  IDN:              no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  Code coverage:    disabled
  SSPI:             no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP:             no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS:            no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP:             enabled
  RTMP:             no      (--with-librtmp)
  Metalink:         no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL:              no      (libpsl not found)
  Alt-svc:          no      (--enable-alt-svc)
  HTTP2:            no      (--with-nghttp2)
  HTTP3:            no      (--with-ngtcp2, --with-quiche)
  ECH:              no      (--enable-ech)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS MQTT POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
  Features:         AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing dynamic versions of zlib and openssl libraries.
One of many possible procedures for building a dynamic curl executable for ARM could be:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-
PREFIX=$(pwd)/sysroot

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
tar zxf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
pushd openssl-1.1.1h
./Configure linux-generic32 shared  -DL_ENDIAN --prefix=${PREFIX} --openssldir=${PREFIX} shared
make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf- PROCESSOR=ARM install
popd

wget https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
pushd zlib-1.2.11
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc ./configure --prefix=${PREFIX}
make CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc all install 
popd

wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz
tar zxf curl-7.73.0.tar.gz
pushd curl-7.73.0
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as  ./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --with-ssl=${PREFIX} --prefix=${PREFIX} --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --without-libidn2
make CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as install
popd


ll -gG sysroot/lib/
total 6796
drwxrwxr-x 4    4096 Nov 16 08:10 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9    4096 Nov 16 07:53 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Nov 16 07:53 engines-1.1/
-rw-r--r-- 1 3199974 Nov 16 07:53 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 16 07:53 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 2087864 Nov 16 07:53 libcrypto.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1    1027 Nov 16 08:10 libcurl.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 16 08:10 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.7.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Nov 16 08:10 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.7.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  407748 Nov 16 08:10 libcurl.so.4.7.0*
-rw-r--r-- 1  578076 Nov 16 07:53 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      13 Nov 16 07:53 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  453684 Nov 16 07:53 libssl.so.1.1*
-rw-r--r-- 1   96210 Nov 16 07:51 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      14 Nov 16 07:51 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.11*
lrwxrwxrwx 1      14 Nov 16 07:51 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11*
-rwxr-xr-x 1   98708 Nov 16 07:51 libz.so.1.2.11*
drwxrwxr-x 2    4096 Nov 16 08:10 pkgconfig/

file sysroot/bin/curl
sysroot/bin/curl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Frant This is very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Frant this is a wonderful answer - thank you so much. The only changes I had to make were for my specific version of gcc and to update to version 1.2.12 of zlib. Note that zlib is required (as shown) in order to avoid the frustrating "openssl not detected" error, even if you think you don't need that feature. I was stuck for a while, but once I built zlib as shown, it built fine. You saved me so many hours!